# Accessing content file in c# web application

Tags: c#, iis, linq-to-xml, virtual-directory, xml

I am having this issue on my mind for 3 days now.
I have an xml file that is marked as `Content` and `Always Copy`.
The file was copied  to:
`C:\Users\avi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ExpressBroker\ExpressBroker\bin\XMLMetadata\Actions.1.xml`

When accessing to the file:

```
//like that:
XDocument actions = XDocument.Load("bin\\XMLMetadata\\Actions.1.xml");
//or like that:
XDocument actions = XDocument.Load("XMLMetadata\\Actions.1.xml");
//or like that:
XDocument actions = XDocument.Load("Actions.1.xml");
```

I get the following exception:
`Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\bin\XMLMetadata\Actions.1.xml'.`

Why is it been searched in the IIS folder? how do i access the file?

I am using IIs Express with VWD2010

Comment: please oh please never use a syntax like the below there is no need for it.use  ~ 100%  not to mention why would you check in bin for a static resource?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have web application's relative path by using

```
Server.MapPath("/")+"bin\\XMLMetadata\\Actions.1.xml"
```

like that.

Comment: what is the namespace of server? i don't have it available. thanks

Comment: @SexyMF - Why do you need a "namespace of server"?

Comment: It should be available on your web application on any page. if you are outside the page then get it from System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server

assuming that you are running this code on web application so the httpcontext's "Current" will not be null.

Comment: why would you not just use whats meant to be used here and thats the '~' character.

Comment: ya ~ too. Also before loading into XDocument, it'd be good to check if file exists by if(System.IO.File.Exists(<filepath>)){ <code> }

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlMetaData/Actions.1.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is static, you might be better off embedding it and using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream().

Comment: local content files outside of resources in web application project are virtually always more efficient and easier to work with and can be deployed as a content type, not to mention you can get iis httpsys caching on them as well for outside accessed static content files.